# Highstock.js display incorrect value if more than 2000 points

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm working with highstock.js and try to make chart with more than 10000 point.
The problem is when I have more than 2000 point value display incorrect, but if point less then 2000 everything work good.

Here is the the what I have done [here](https://jsfiddle.net/VasyaCV/3hop6s12/12/)

```
Highcharts.stockChart('container',
 {
          rangeSelector: {

                buttons: [
                    {
                        type: 'month',
                        count: 1,
                        text: '1m'
                    },
                    {
                        type: 'month',
                        count: 6,
                        text: '6m'
                    },
                    {
                        type: 'year',
                        count: 1,
                        text: '1y'
                    },
                    {
                        type: 'year',
                        count: 3,
                        text: '3y'
                    },
                    {
                        type: 'all',
                        text: 'All'
                    }
                ],
                selected: 2
            },

            scrollbar: {
                enabled: false
            },

            yAxis: {
                labels: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        return this.value + '%';
                    }
                }
            },

            plotOptions:{
                series:{
                    turboThreshold: 10000
                }
            },
            series: [{
                data: data,
                dataGrouping: {
                 forced: true,
                 units: [
                 ['day', [1]]
                 ]
                 },
                tooltip: {
                    headerFormat: '',
                    pointFormat: '<table><tr><td style="padding:0">Purchased: <b>{point.x:%d/%m/%Y}</b></td></tr><br>'+
                                 '<tr><td style="padding:0">Yield On Cost: <b>{point.y}%</b></td></tr></table>',
                    footerFormat: '',
                    shared: true,
                    useHTML: true,
                    valueDecimals: 2,
                    split: false
                }
            }]
        });
```

Now I have when more than 2000 point such result [link](https://clip2net.com/s/41rfM0E/)
and when near 1800 point result is [link](https://clip2net.com/s/41rfMFl/)

Comment: What do you mean saying "value display incorrect"? Perhaps it is happening because of Highstock data grouping: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.line.dataGrouping?

Comment: Yes, I think that this happening because of grouping. Chart grouped and show me point with date like start of the week. Than I added 
  dataGrouping: {
                 forced: true,
                 units: [['day', [1]]]
                 }
and date became for each day. Is it possible disable grouping or manage it in right way?

Comment: Yes, you can disable it: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.line.dataGrouping.enabled

Comment: I disabled grouping and chart began looks like [link](https://jsfiddle.net/VasyaCV/3hop6s12/13/)

Comment: It's because your data is not sorted properly.

Comment: Thank you. I understand what I did wrong. Data wasn't sorted and repeated

Comment: Exactly ;) Can I add it as an answer and you will mark it as a correct one??

Comment: yes, you can add

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is caused by Highstock data grouping which is enabled by default. You can disable it like that:

```
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
  series: [{
    name: 'AAPL',
    dataGrouping: {
      enabled: false
    },
    data: [
      [1539264600000, 214.45],
      [1539351000000, 222.11],
      [1539610200000, 217.36],
      [1539696600000, 222.15],
      [1539783000000, 221.19],
      [1539869400000, 216.02],
      ...
    ]
  }]
});
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/b1yjsaun/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.line.dataGrouping.enabled